# Unnamed objects formed during derivation

Tags: c++

Abstract classes i.e classes which have at least one pure virtual function do not allow object instantiation. But when we derive a concrete class from this abstract class and define all the pure virtual functions, we can instantiate an object of this class.

But when derived object is created, first an unnamed base class object has to be created. How does this happen? I mean how can this unnamed abstract base class object be created, if its creation is not allowed.

Comment: This is probably compiler-specific.

Comment: Your fundamental assumption that a base class object must first be created is flawed. An object is a full object, the base class part of derived type is a sub-object (and **not an object** it its own right). This is explicitly spelled out in the standard See Section 1.8 [intro.object]. Paragraph 3 defines a `complete object of x` where x is part of the object. Also Section 3.8 Object lifetime [basic.life] which explicitly states: The lifetime of an **object** of type T begins when: 1) Storage has been obtained 2) Initialization completes.

Answer (score 3):

That's like saying the human heart can't exist as it needs the human. But when we create a human we must first create the heart but how do we create the heart when it can't exist without the human.

The answer is because we create them together they are all part of a single entity.
The heart and human are created together.
No object actually exists until the constructor fully completes at which point heart and human exist as a single object.

Answer (score 3):

You have confused “not possible” with “not allowed”. Instantiation of abstract classes is possible for compiler, of course; it's just not allowed to programmer.

Comment: I think Eugene is right, compiler can create this unnamed abstract base , but not the programmer.

Unnamed base class object has to be created. Example, consider a base class which throws exception when more than one object of its kind exist in the program. This book-keeping can be done simply by using a static int data member. Lets call this SingleInstance_Base class.Now suppose a class is derived from this base class called DerivedFromSingleInstance_Base.

Now if we create two objects like:

SingleInstance_Base objBase;
DerivedFromSingleInstance_Base objDerived;

Comment: we will get a run time error in the second statement, as an unnamed 
SingleInstance_Base object is created first and then the DerivedFromSingleInstance_Base starts to get created.

Answer (score 0):

> when derived object is created, first an unnamed base class object has
>   to be created. How does this happen?

IMO, **base class object is not created** in the way we see. Yes we do provide constructor and methods etc in base class, but they are merely tools for initialization/assignments.

In actual, derived class is inheriting base part of it, so ultimately we are creating derived class object only. Analogical example:

```
struct B {
  int b;
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct D : B {
  int d;
  virtual void foo () {}
};
```

While creating object, compiler looks `D` as,

```
struct D {
  int b,d;
  virtual void foo () {}
};
```

It sees that `D` is fulfilling all the conditions to be able to instantiate an object and it creates the object.